# insering images and text into a <div>

Tags: javascript

I have an empty `<div>` where I output some information using a

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output
```

If I would like to have it output 4*5 , how could I replace the '*' sign with a custom picture of a multiplication sign so it outputs:"4'multiplication sign image'5"

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
   '4<img src="multiplication_sign.png">5';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = '4 <img src="url_to_image" alt="" /> 5';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

And if you want to replace it dynamically using your current output, you can do something like:

```
var output = "4 * 5".replace("*", '<img src="url_to_image" alt="" />');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

I assume you'll want to do this for `+`, `-` and `/` as well.

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LhGzr/